# Parse.com with ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, parse-platform

how do I connect my ASP.NET MVC project to parse?
I had put the parse.initialize in global.asax applicationStart function with my appId and .netID.
And then i tried to use the following code to register a user.

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var user = new ParseUser()
            {
                Username = model.Email,
                Password = model.Password,
                Email = model.Email
            };

            await user.SignUpAsync();
```

but it's return an error: **The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.**
i figured that it must have no authentication to my ParseAPP or the connection did not start at all?

Comment: using proxy credentials in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Solve the error, has nothing specific to do with Parse
Just add the below code to web.config and it's worked.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```